# How can give GRANT rights to a database on remote server via MYSQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, heroku, mysql-workbench

I have a cleadb database on heroku. When I'm uploading my database from local disk to heroku it's giving error

```
ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'user_name_of_cleardb_at_heroku'@'%' to database 'i_am_uploading'
```

This is some permission issue. How to I give GRANT RIGHTS to my database on heroku ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to comment out bind-address line in my.cnf to allow connections from outside localhost:

```
#bind-address      = 127.0.0.1
```

Then re-start mysqld

Comment: @d g thanks for the quick reply. Can you please be more elaborative about how to do it ?  I have never worked with mysqlworkbench before

Comment: it's a server side thing - not a workbench setting you can change. I would suggest contacting ClearDB directly.